# What is the intended use of the --flat option to dsymutil

Tags: c, xcode, macos, lldb, dwarf

The `dsymutil` man page indicates that there is an option to `dsymutil` called `--flat` which will create a single file debug package, with the `.dwarf` extension. I tried this, and while the expected `.dwarf` files do get created, it doesn't appear that `lldb` actually loads them, unlike if you generate a regular `.dSYM` directory. I can't find a whole lot of documentation other than what the man page says.

Is there an intended scenario for such files, or is this something left over from long ago that should no longer be used?

It was appealing because as a single file it would be easier to manage in a build system, rather than needing to manage the generated `.dSYM` directory.

```
$ cat > hello_world.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World\n";
    return 0;
}

$ clang++ ./hello_world.cpp -g -c -o hello_world.o
$ clang++ ./hello_world.o -o hello_world

$ dsymutil ./hello_world

$ tree ./hello_world.dSYM
./hello_world.dSYM
└── Contents
    ├── Info.plist
    └── Resources
        └── DWARF
            └── hello_world

$ lldb hello_world
(lldb) target create "./hello_world"
Current executable set to './hello_world' (x86_64).
(lldb) image list
[  0] 7984B8FE-1C4E-3468-9819-C3BE4E50456D 0x0000000100000000 .../hello_world
      .../hello_world.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/hello_world

$ \rm -rf hello_world.dSYM
$ dsymutil --flat ./hello_world
$ file hello_world.dwarf
hello_world.dwarf: Mach-O 64-bit dSYM companion file x86_64

(lldb) target create "./hello_world"
Current executable set to './hello_world' (x86_64).
(lldb) image list
[  0] 7984B8FE-1C4E-3468-9819-C3BE4E50456D 0x0000000100000000 .../hello_world
[  1] F217F7F8-A795-3109-B77F-B1E2277F3E3B 0x0000000000000000 /usr/lib/dyld
```

As you can see, `lldb` happily and automatically finds and loads the `.dSYM`, but doesn't do so for the `.dwarf` file version.

Is there a way to make `lldb` load these files, or, better, load them automatically? Other tools? Is there some other step required to "link up" the executable to the `.dwarf` file, like an analog to `--add-gnu-debuglink`? Or is `dsymutil --flat` something not really supported and to be avoided? Are there any use cases for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--flat` option isn't really supported. It exists for testing, where we usually want to check the generated DWARF, rather than the dSYM bundle structure which should always be the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The current situation where .dSYM is a directory (bundle) presents some challenges for build systems. None is insurmountable, but I think it would be helpful if a mechanism to support something like flat .dwarf files could be implemented. Or perhaps just a -z flag to `dsymutil` to have it construct a gzipped directory and then adding LLDB support for reading from such a thing directly. Build systems, especially ones that do end-to-end caching, tend to work best with files, not directories, and teaching them the .dSYM substructure is a pain. Just my thoughts...